# $(f_n(x))$ converges to a discontinuous function Counterexample

Tags: uniform-convergence

If the sequence of functions $(f_n(x))$ converges to a discontinuous function
$f(x)$ on a set S, then the sequence does not converge uniformly on S.

If a function $f(x)$ is defined on [−1, 1] and continuous at $x = 0$, then f
is continuous on some open interval containing zero

Can anyone show me a counter example to these? I am struggling to find one, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f_n=x^n$ on $[0,1]$.

This converges to $f(x)=0$ for $x<1$, and $f(1)=1$.

So this functioon is discontinuous, and the convergence isn't uniform.

Comment: Thank you very much man can you also explain a counter example to this awsell If a function $f(x)$  is defined on [−1, 1] and continuous at $x=0$ , then f is continuous on some open interval containing zero

Comment: o wait remember its supposed to be a counter example

Comment: @Pasie15: I think Andre's answer below gives you the second counterexample. So I am not adding any more :).

Comment: @Pasie15: Did you mean an example of  $f_n$'s converging uniformly to a discontinuous function? If so, just take your favorite discontinuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$, and let $f_n=f$ for all $n$. The convergence is trivially uniform.

Comment: On the other hand, a sequence of **continuous** functions can't converge uniformly to a discontinuous function.

Answer (score 3):

For your second question, let $g(x)=0$ if $x$ is rational, and let $g(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational. Let $f(x)=xg(x)$. Then $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ and nowhere else.